# i want to Search for points within a raster layer using ST_Contains. Keep getting no function matches given error

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have made a Simple points shapefile with seven points and I would like to be able to query which of these points are contained within the boundary of the raster layer.

```
SELECT "points inside raster_test".name 
FROM "points inside raster_test", myraster3
where ST_Within ("points inside raster_test".geom, myraster3.rast);
```

I keep getting the following error-

```
ERROR:  function st_contains(geometry, raster) does not exist   
LINE 3: where ST_contains ("points inside raster_test".geom, myraste...  
              ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types.
You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Do I have to write this query differently because there is a raster instead of another vector layer? I have tried using a vector polygon with the same points and wrote it exactly the same and it has given me the results I have desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the bounding box of the raster.
Something like this:

```
where st_within("points inside raster_test".geom, st_envelope(myraster3.rast))
```

Should do it.

([ref. to docs.](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Envelope.html))

Comment: is the bounding box of a raster the exact size of the raster? or is it like the bounding box of vector object?

Comment: It's a bounding box, rather than an exact footprint. It returns: "The  polygon is defined by the corner points of the bounding box ((MINX, MINY), (MINX, MAXY), (MAXX, MAXY), (MAXX, MINY), (MINX, MINY))", in the crs of your raster.